# Why do negative oxidation states not extend to -8?

Tags: oxidation-state

There are oxidation states from -4 to +8

Why do the negative oxidation states not go all the way down to -8? I mean if an atom is hypervalent meaning that it can have more than an octet than that means it can have potentially 8 bonds(counting a double bond as 2 bonds and a triple bond as 3 bonds respectively) to other atoms more electronegative than itself and thus Xenon can have a +8 oxidation state and some metals can as well.

Doesn't that also mean that a hypervalent atom can have 8 bonds to other atoms less electronegative than itself and thus have a -8 oxidation state?

Comment: Actually it's now -5 to +9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do the negative oxidation states not go all the way down to -8?

Let's think about what we would need for this to occur - i.e. an oxidation state of -8.

We would need a central atom that has considerable electronegativity - one that is at least more electronegative than its attached atoms. This already excludes numerous molecules; most molecules' central atoms are, on a relative basis, more *electropositive* rather than electronegative.

In addition, this atom would need to have one of the following configurations; "allocated" refers to the assignment of oxidation state - since oxidation states are assigned on the premise that all bonding is ionic - the more electronegative element in a bonding configuration is "allocated" all the bonding electrons in the calculation of oxidation states. I.e. in H2O, the oxygen would be allocated both pairs of bonding electrons in the H-O bonds, and oxygen would then "have" 8 electrons, and its oxidation state would be -2.

1 valence electron and be "allocated" 9 electrons

2 valence electrons and be "allocated" 10 electrons

3 valence electrons and be "allocated" 11 electrons,

and on the other extreme:

6 valence electrons and be "allocated" 14 electrons,

7 valence electrons and be "allocated" 15 electrons,

8 valence electrons and be "allocated" 16 electrons.

As we can see, the first set of criteria are basically incompatible. Elements only having 1 or 2 valence electrons are going to be small (on a relative basis). These elements would also *much rather* be oxidized than reduced. Oxidation allows these elements to easily become isoelectronic with a noble gas.

The other set of criteria for a negative 8 oxidation state is also hard to fulfill. None of the group 6 elements except the possibility of sulfur and elements below it are hypervalent - i.e. they can accommodate more than 8 valence electrons. Even if we consider sulfur as able to accommodate *12* valence electrons (as some depictions of sulfuric acid suggest) we must remember that sulfur is not very electronegative and unlikely to be allocated any electrons.

Comment: Sulfur is more electronegative than quite a few elements, especially metals, but also the oxygen group elements below sulfur, Nitrogen group elements below N, Carbon group elements, Boron group elements, Xenon, Iodine, and Astatine.

Comment: Right, but I can't think of any molecules or ions in which sulfur is the central element and metals are ligands, the other way around yes. Such as silver sulfide.

Comment: Doesn't the possibility of a -8 oxidation state only require that a hypervalent atom has 8 bonds(covalent(with a double bond counted as 2 and a triple bond counted as 3 respectively) or ionic) to 8 atoms less electronegative than itself, not that it is the central atom?

Comment: Well, you also have to consider how many electrons the element has in its valence.

Comment: right but it has to have 8 bonds to something less electronegative than itself(with a double bond counted as 2 and a triple bond as 3 respectively) whether they are covalent, ionic, or both(even though it is rare to have both types of bonds in the same compound unless you are talking about a hydroxide or something along those lines.)